# connect node project to existingstrongloop api

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I have been looking around everywhere to find some documentation on how to connect to a strongloop api which is already live. I am currently in development of a new node.js project but need guidance on how to connect and use the api.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a REST API in general, all you need is an HTTP client. You can use something low-level like [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), or, a popular HTTP REST client like [Postman](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), which can handle things like authentication on an API more easily.